# Displacement in viewport looks NOTHING like render? Adaptive or not makes no diff

Tags: displacement

I have an appended procedural texture with displacement that looks great in the viewport.
As soon as I render it, it looks like utter trash. It doesn't even resemble the planar version of the displacement texture.

I thought it was an issue with adaptive subdiv, but no - just tried with normal subdiv and same issue.

V3.0 used, and it makes no difference what dicing scale or camera is used.

Screenshots attached showing the same camera view in both viewport and render window, subdiv settings are visible.
CUDA GPU's enabled and in experimental mode (which shouldn't even be necessary for regular subdiv, but anyway...)

What the hell?
Images link in case the inline doesn't work:
https://postimg.cc/gallery/Jhhw32z

Blend file: https://easyupload.io/1z284k

[image: Adaptive:]

[image: Regular:]

Comment: Hi :). The Wave Texture Distortion is keyframed. Viewport shows Distortion = 10, but it renders with only 1 which looks bad. Redo or remove your keyframes ;)

Comment: Holy freaking cats! Thank you, this was driving me absolutely mental.

Comment: Anytime ;) good luck with your project